# Why logical operator false didnt work on conditions

Tags: c++

I just would like to know (trust me, I tried to search it) why I can not put the 'false' logic operator in this sentence:

```
while (input.compare("add") == false and input.compare("remove") == false and input.compare("list") == false)
{
    cout << endl << "(" << input << ")" << " is not a command system." << endl;
    cout << "Please, put only the commands available.";
    getline(cin, input);
}
```

This code compiles, but it didn't work. However, with the != 0 operator, it works.

```
while (input.compare("add") != 0 and input.compare("remove") != 0 and input.compare("list") != 0)
{
    cout << endl << "(" << input << ")" << " is not a command system." << endl;
    cout << "Please, put only the commands available.";
    getline(cin, input);
}
```

Can please some one say me why this happen?

Comment: You 're probably confused due to the fact that `std::string::compare` returns `0` instead of `true` when strings matched and `>0` or `<0` when strings doesn't match (depending on which string's characters are shorter/longer). That said, your second case is correct while first is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You changed the meaning of the code between the two samples. Let's assume that the `compare()` method returns a `bool` value.

In the first piece of code, you wrote `input.compare("add") == false`. This expression is true if and only if `compare()` returns `false`.

In the second piece of code, you wrote `input.compare("add") != 0`. If `compare()` returns `true`, then it is converted to `1`, which is unequal to `0` and thus `true`. Hence this expression is true if and only if `compare()` returns `true` - which is the exact opposite of what the first piece of code does. This totally changes the behavior of your code.

---

The preferred way to write this expression should involve no mention of `true` or `false` at all. For example:

```
input.compare("add") and !input.compare("remove") etc.
```

Don't write like this (though it behaves equivalently):

```
input.compare("add") == true and input.compare("remove") == false etc.
```

Comment: In C++, false _can be converted to an integer_ as 0.  false is not 0.

Comment: I must be confusing it with C then.

Comment: In C, `false` is indeed defined as 0 in `<stdbool.h>`. Notable: they added `_Bool` to C some 17 years ago.

Comment: Put simply, the first snippets has a structure of (is false AND is false AND is false) while the second one has a structure of (not false AND not false AND not false)